# How to GROUP BY 2 different columns together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 columns having users id participating in a transaction, source_id and destination_id. I'm building a function to sum all transactions grouped by any user participating on it, either as source or as destination.

The problem is, when I do:

```
select count (*) from transactions group by source_id, destination_id
```

it will first group by source, then by destination, I want to group them together. Is it possible using only SQL?

Sample Data

```
source_user_id    destination_user_id
1                 4
3                 4
4                 1
3                 2
```

Desired result:

```
Id Count
4 - 3 (4 appears 3 times in any of the columns)
3 - 2 (3 appears 2 times in any of the columns)
1 - 2 (1 appear 2 times in any of the columns)
2 - 1 (1 appear 1 time in any of the columns)
```

As you can see on the example result, I want to know the number of times an id will appear in any of the 2 fields.

Comment: instead of the ps that you posted, you should clarify your question by posting some sample data and the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all` to get the id's into one column and get the counts.

```
select id,count(*) 
from (select source_id as id from tbl
      union all
      select destination_id from tbl
     ) t
group by id 
order by count(*) desc,id
```

Answer (score 0):

edited to add: Thank you for clarifying your question. The following isn't what you need.

Sounds like you want to use the concatenate function. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(source_id,"_",destination_id)
```

The underscore is intended to distinguish "source_id=1, destination_id=11" from "source_id=11, destination_id=1". (We want them to be 1_11 and 11_1 respectively.) If you expect these IDs to contain underscores, you'd have to handle this differently, but I assume they're integers.

Answer (score 0):

It may look like this.

```
Select id, count(total )  from
(select source_id as id, count (destination_user_id) as total from transactions group by source_id
union
select destination_user_id as id , count (source_id) as total from transactions group by destination_user_id ) q group by id
```